# Obtain a value to a DataSource Parameters

Tags: asp.net

Well, Im new in ASP net and I just wanna know how to add a parameter to  a SQLDatasource
I have a control (dropdawnlist) with some data:

```
<td>
                 <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:idiomas, moneda_origen %>"></asp:Label><br />                
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOriginCurrency" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                    DataTextField="MON_NOMBRE" DataValueField="MON_MONEDA_ID" DataSourceID="dsOriginCurrency">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:idiomas, moneda_destino %>"></asp:Label><br />                
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDestinationCurrency" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                    DataTextField="MON_NOMBRE" DataValueField="MON_MONEDA_ID" DataSourceID="dsDestinationCurrency">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
```

and I just wanna get the value from the any of those DropDawnlist to add as a parameter in my SQLDataSource when Updating

```
 <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="BOF_FEES_ID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BOF_MONEDA_ORIGEN_ID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BOF_DESDE" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BOF_HASTA" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BOF_FEES" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BOF_MARKUP" Type="Double" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BOF_INCREMENT_PERCENT" Type="Double" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BOF_BOOKINGCURRENCY_ID" Type="Double" />
    </UpdateParameters>
```

There is a form to do it directly in ASP Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<asp:Parameter/>`, you need to use `<asp:ControlParameter/>`

Here is an example of this parameter

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropdownListControl" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="ParameterName" />
```